# How to initiate suggested-edits in non-open questions, with an example

Tags: support, edits

I can't yet edit on SO: I have a 31 rep.

I'd like to make a suggested edit to, or to personally edit and fix this [closed] question:

[Why are modal dialog boxes evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361493/why-are-modal-dialog-boxes-evil)

which has as one of its answers, (edit mine):

> I feel many descent (sic) questions are closed in StackOverflow :(
> I thought high rating of questions and answers indicate they
> are useful. – Yasen Dec 16, 2014 at 11:45

The "descent" to "decent" edit addresses *lots* of reasons and intents.

The OP is closed. I can click to suggest an edit to *the question,* but not to suggest an edit to *its answers.* I know about SO's ***suggested-edits*** tag. One option is to ask a meta-SO question, note the edit, note the URL, add a *suggested-edits* tag, and move on.

Here's the point. First, I've attached the suggested-edits tag to this question. Please make that edit. :-)

Lastly, though, please change my editing status to allow me to make those suggested-edits.

An interesting, incidental note is that the first versions of this question used the term [closed] in its title, which got flagged by the review bot. That was a great catch, actually, although I thought it was sorta *geeky humorous,* too.

Comment: Even if you could suggest such an edit, please don't! The number of reviewers is very limited, submitting suggestions for such minor edits will tie up review capacities that cannot be used for substantial changes.

Comment: "*One option is to ask a meta-SO question, note the edit, note the URL, add a suggested-edits tag, and move on.*" no, that's not how suggested edits work nor how [[tag:suggested-edits]] is supposed to be used. You're not just supposed to drop your suggested edit on MSO and expect somebody else to apply it. The tag is to *ask about suggested edits*.

Comment: What about the word after "closed in"?

Comment: The title of ***every single*** page on Stack Overflow has it printed in large friendly letters: "Stack Overflow" (see also *[Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange, Inc. Trademarks](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)* (the last section)).

Answer (score 12):

This isn't an answer.  It is a comment.

[image]

You cannot edit comments, no matter what rep you are.  Mods can but they very seldom do.

To edit posts you're going to [have to earn that rep yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).  We can't just *give* it to you.

Tell ya what.  Let's flag this comment as "no longer needed".  It was written a long time ago and adds no value to the actual question itself, as it's not asking for clarifications or anything like that.

Comment: "Mods can [edit comments] but they very seldom do." Just to add some context to this, I've been a mod on Writing.SE for about 18 months now, and I can count on one hand the number of times I've done this. Usually, it's when I'm tidying up a comment thread and need to remove any dangling references to deleted comments, or I've converted an answer into a comment. I wouldn't bother editing a comment just to fix a typo.

Comment: The question itself isn't great and maybe should be deleted. Just a thought though.

Comment: Maybe a historical lock @Dharman?  I could see a lot of people who have misgivings about the benefits of modals coming to the site to see this question.  Then again it's pretty low traffic so there's not a lot of impetus to really keep it around.  Your call.

Comment: @F1Krazy yup... very rare... I've apparently edited 54 in ~6 years... (and that's probably on the high side...)

Comment: I've edited 2110 comments (on main, 262 on Meta) over a shorter period than Jon. The frequency depends on the individual moderator. I *strongly* prefer editing to salvage comments that contain some information of value over deleting them outright. This one, of course, contains nothing of value and should not be edited, just deleted.